# how to set the timestamp/date on a perforce changelist/commit

Tags: perforce

In Git, I can set the environment variable GIT_COMMITTER_DATE etc to set the date of the commit to be anything I want (without affecting the order of commits).

Is there a way to do the equivalent in Perforce (p4)? I created a 'Date' field in the submit spec that opened up with 'p4 submit', but when I do 'p4 filelog' the time at which I ran the submit command shows up 'p4 filelog' output. I want it to show the date I entered for 'Date' during 'p4 submit'.

Any way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible. The `Date:` field you are referring to is read-only and notes the date, where the change-list was last modified (from the manual for [p4 change](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/change.html#1040665)).

Answer (score 2):

If you are superuser or admin you can edit an existing Changelist's
`Date:` or `User:` fields.

```
p4 change -f <revision>
```

See the [man page for p4 change](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/change.html).